# Enviar correo a dos mails y responder solo a uno

Tags: php, html5, formularios, email

Estoy trabajando con un formulario PHP en el que el usuario pone sus datos (entre ellos su correo) y se manda un mail a dos direcciones de correo, la mía y la de mi cliente.
Mi problema es que cuando pongo "responder" dentro de la bandera de entrada, me aparecen dos correos como remitentes: el que ingresó el usuario, y el de mi cliente.
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solo me figure el del usuario? Ya que al momento de responder, no hace falta que ese correo se le envíe a mi cliente.
Necesito que alguien me pase un ejemplo del código o qué debo agregar o quitar de mi código.

```js
$to      = 'mimail@mail.com,mailcliente@mail.com';
$subject = 'Formulario';
$message = " La siguiente persona solicita una cotización:<br/>
<b>Nombre:</b> $nombre<br/>
<b>Teléfono:</b> $tel<br/>
<b>E-Mail:</b> $email<br/>
";

$headers = 'From: mimail@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit;
```

Comment: ¿Qué contiene la variable `$email`? No se ve cómo la inicializas...

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he resuelto. Para ello, cambié un par de cosas en el `From`

```js
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: thankyou.html');
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

No recomiendo que lo hagas de esta manera, ya que los correos electrónicos pueden recibir spam.

Te recomiendo que uses phpmailer.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
 try {


        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);          
            //Server settings
        $mail->isSMTP();       
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'example@example.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'pass';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('example@example.com', 'name');

        if(is_array($this->Emails)){
            foreach($this->Emails as $email){
                $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
            }
        }
        else{
            $mail->addAddress($this->Emails);     // Add a recipient
        }

        if(isset($this->Attachments)){

            if(is_array($this->Attachments)){
                foreach($this->Attachments as $Attachment){
                    $mail->addAttachment($Attachment);         // Add attachments
                }
            }
            else{
                $mail->addAttachment($this->Attachments);         // Add attachments
            }

        }

        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $this->Subject;
        $mail->Body    = $this->Body;

        $mail->send();
        return true;
```